# how to transform code section into function in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code that does all the work, but I'm having trouble passing it to a function that takes the array as an argument.

```
void main() 

{
  var pairs = [[9, 5, 1], [3, 6]];
 
  var example= pairs.expand((pair) => pair).toList();

  example.sort();

  print('Result: $example'); 
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(List) => Iterable'. SO, you can pass with `List<List>` type.

```
void main() 

{
  var pairs = [[3, 2, 1], [4, 6, 5], [], [9, 7, 8]];
  getListOfData(pairs);
}

getListOfData(List<List> pairs){
  var desempacotada = pairs.expand((pair) => pair).toList();
  desempacotada.sort();

  print('Result: $desempacotada'); //Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```